# Recuperar dados da array php através de valor do índice

Tags: php, array

Minha array no print_r exibe assim:

```
[
    {
        "id": "A220", 
        "name": "Dipirona", 
        "symbol": "R$", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_br": "8.4", 
        "price_usd": "2.0"
        "total_supply": "287.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000.0", 
        "last_updated": "1519152868"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "A220", 
        "name": "Eno", 
        "symbol": "R$", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_br": "2.4", 
        "price_usd": "1.0"
        "total_supply": "341.0", 
        "max_supply": "1200.0", 
        "last_updated": "1615122869"
    }
]
```

Como recuperar os valores do ID: A220, por exemplo, que são os dados do produto "Dipirona", e armazenar em outro array somente os dados do "Dipirona" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você deseja filtrar esse array pelo índice **id** e **name**. Para fazer isso você pode utilizar a função `array_filter` do PHP.

Exemplo:

Filtrando esse array pelo **id A220** e Pelo **name Dipirona**

```
<?php 

    $arr = "..."; //Array que você mandou no exemplo acima

    $novoArray = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
        return $item['id'] == "A220" && $item['name'] == "Dipirona"; 
    });
```

**Resultado:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => A220
            [name] => Dipirona
            [symbol] => R$
            [rank] => 1
            [price_br] => 8.4
            [price_usd] => 2.0
            [total_supply] => 287.0
            [max_supply] => 21000.0
            [last_updated] => 1519152868
        )

)
```

Caso deseje obter o primeiro índice (`$novoArray[0]`), utilize o comando `current`:

```
$novoArray = current($novoArray);
```

Então, o resultado será esse:

```
Array
(
    [id] => A220
    [name] => Dipirona
    [symbol] => R$
    [rank] => 1
    [price_br] => 8.4
    [price_usd] => 2.0
    [total_supply] => 287.0
    [max_supply] => 21000.0
    [last_updated] => 1519152868
)
```

Comment: Gabriel, pode me ajudar? Tem esse link https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ e gostaria de pegar esse array e importar para um array local, como que faz?

Comment: Você pode usar o comando `file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')` para puxar os dados e o comando `json_decode()` para converter de json para array. A linha ficaria assim: `$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'))`

Comment: Relacionado à sua resposta, fiz o código adaptado com a URL mas não retorna nada.

Comment: Olhe se não esqueceu o ponto e vírgula no final (;). Não coloquei na linha acima.

Comment: Tentei executar esse script agora aqui na minha maqui, funcionou corretamente. 
`$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'));`
 A variável `$dados` contém o array com os itens dessa API.

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar um forach para ler a array
Supundo que sua array chama-se $arr

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $prod){
        echo $prod['id']
        // ai é so chamar a variavel $prod com o indice
    }
?>
```

Ou se quiser acessar diretamente sem loop

```
$arr[0]['id']; 
$arr[1]['id'];
```

Comment: Não deu certo, apareceu o erro: 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testes\index.php on line 59
h

foreach($remedios as  $remedio){
echo $remedio['id'];
}